# Pulling a number from a string

Tags: awk

I am having difficulty with pulling just the User Number and the Error form this dataset. Where I am going wrong?

Source data:

```
[319041185] :: [2013/08/28 08:10:22.702 P2D98 T020 d] PSComAccountsClient.UserPasswordVerify User=6272820002384270, Password=[not logged], AccessLevel=User
.
.
[319041253] :: [2013/08/28 08:10:22.718 P2D98 T020 e] [FunctorBase.Execute] (ErrorCode=Pedi.InternalError) An internal server error occurred. The account could not be found.
```

Command:

```
awk "{if (/User=/) {s=$NF; gsub (/[^0-9]/,\"\",s);} if (s==/[0=9]/ && /ErrorCode=/) {q=sub (/.*InternalError\\")"/,\"\"); } printf s; printf q}" file
```

Current Output:

```
NULL
```

Intended Output:

```
6272820002384270 An internal server error occurred. The account could not be found.
```

Comment: You can edit your post with more details, no need to leave details in comments

Comment: You've showed some sample input and your attempted solution so that's a great start, now finish off your question by posting the expected output.

Comment: I was able to do this with the following:

Code:

   awk "{if (/User=/) {s=$0; sub(/.*User=/,\"\",s); sub(/P.*/,\"\",s);} if (s&& /ErrorCode=/) { sub (/.*InternalError\\")"/,\"\"); } printf s; print}" "file"|grep "server error" |awk -F"," "{ if($2 ~ /error/) {print}}" | Sort| Uniq

Answer (score 2):

You could also use grep, e.g.

```
grep -Po 'User=\K[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach using `GNU awk` if the file structure is consistent is to set multiple field separators and just print the field you need:

```
$ awk -F'[=, ]' '{print $10}' file
6272820002384270
```

If the field number could change from line to line the just loop over all the fields:

```
$ awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~"User=")print substr($i,6)}' file
6272820002384270
```

Alternately by setting the value of `RS`:

```
$ awk '$1=="User"{print $2}'  RS=',? ' FS='=' file
6272820002384270
```

Comment: +1. There's nothing GNU awk specific about any of those solutions exept the last one, though, The others would work with any modern awk.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

```
str='Source: [319041185] :: [2013/08/28 08:10:22.702 P2D98 T020 d] PSComAccountsClient.UserPasswordVerify User=6272820002384270, Password=[not logged], AccessLevel=User'
```

Using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=User=)\d+' <<< "str"
```

Using awk:

```
awk -F'[,=]+' '{print $2}' <<< "str"
```